# How to end Swing program with always-on-top dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, joptionpane, always-on-top

How to finish the program? I mean that after executing it and closing the dialog the Java process does not finish. It can be viewed in Eclipse so the red icon is still active and the program does not finish.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            frame, "test info", "test header", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create a `JFrame` , just pass `null` as the first parameter of `showMessageDialog` .

Comment: Why are you creating JFrame in the first place? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Berger I need the dialog window to be on top.

Comment: @Pshemo  I need the dialog window to be on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose the frame after the dialog is set visible.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            frame, "test info", "test header", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        // When a frame is disposed, the exit action will be called.
        frame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to give a focus for displayed window? Because when other window is active the dialog appears on ton but not focused.

Comment: *"Is there a way to give a focus for displayed window?"* Yes. For a more complete answer, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not call method like:
`frame.show();` or `frame.setVisible(true);`

If you call one of the methods then the frame will show up and then if you close the frame, it will stop to run.

### code update:

```
     private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "test info", "test header", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
```

Comment: I do not want the `frame` to be visible. It only must be on top

Comment: A non-visible frame on top doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following close the process. But it is little bit hard.

```
System.exit(0);
```